# matrix middle entries

Tags: matrices

How to write such a matrix [image] in latex, matrix A being in the middle of the 4th quadrant?

Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the unusual spacing in the lower-left is intentional, you could use `nicematrix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \det A & 0 & 0\\
\Block{2-2}{\begin{matrix}0&0\\0&0\end{matrix}} & &\Block{2-2} A\\
\\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```